# Heroku restart not the same as Nodejs restart

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I have a Nodejs application which uses mysql database. I have written a function that runs everytime the server restarts. This function updates the mysql schema based on schema versions I have created. If I connect an empty database for example my schemaCheck function will build everything from the scratch.

Now, I have a database connected to heroku which had some tables. I deleted all the tables from mysql workbench and ran the:

```
heroku ps:restart myApp
```

This was supposed to rebuild all of my tables and display various console messages.

The console says that the restarting is successful but I know that it did not restart because it does not display any of the console message that it is supposed to show in `heroku logs --tail`

However, if I do a `git push` to heroku all of my functions that are supposed to run on server restart runs properly. The `tail` message starts with

```
Build started by user dave32@mct.edu
```

Do I have to build everytime to restart my Heroku server? Building takes a lot of time

Comment: Is your code running within your server.js file or is it part of your package.json and is a specific command?

Comment: It is running within the server.js file

Comment: Can you share the code that actually executes, I am curious to see if there is something else going on.  Also could you add a **console.log('test')** next to where the code for the database is supposed to run.